# Spark java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I ran the following udf using scipy cosine similarity on Spark on YARN. I first tested this on a sample 30 observations of the data. and it ran fine and creates a cosine similarity matrix in 5 sec.

here is the code:

```
def cosineSimilarity(df):
    """ Cosine similarity of the each document with other

    """

    from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
    from pyspark.sql.types import DoubleType
    from scipy.spatial import distance

    cosine = udf(lambda v1, v2: (
     float(1-distance.cosine(v1, v2)) if v1 is not None and v2 is not None else None),
     DoubleType())

    # Creating a cross product of the table to get the cosine similarity vectors 

    crosstabDF=df.withColumnRenamed('id','id_1').withColumnRenamed('w2v_vector','w2v_vector_1')\
    .join(df.withColumnRenamed('id','id_2').withColumnRenamed('w2v_vector','w2v_vector_2'))

    similardocs_df= crosstabDF.withColumn('cosinesim', cosine("w2v_vector_1","w2v_vector_2"))

    return similardocs_df

#similardocs_df=cosineSimilarity(w2vdf.select('id','w2v_vector'))


similardocs_df=cosineSimilarity(w2vdf_sample.select('id','w2v_vector'))
```

Then I tried to pass the whole matrix (58K records) and it runs for a while and then is giving me the following error:

I would like to mention , one time it did run for the whole data within 5 minutes. But now on the whole data it is giving me this error while it runs on sample with no issues.

```
WARN  org.spark_project.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler (ServletHandler.java:doHandle(667)) - Error for /jobs/
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.getDispatcherType()Ljavax/servlet/DispatcherType;
    at org.spark_project.jetty.servlets.gzip.AbstractCompressedStream.doCompress(AbstractCompressedStream.java:248)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.servlets.gzip.AbstractCompressedStream.checkOut(AbstractCompressedStream.java:354)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.servlets.gzip.AbstractCompressedStream.write(AbstractCompressedStream.java:229)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:221)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implWrite(StreamEncoder.java:282)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:125)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:135)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.write(OutputStreamWriter.java:220)
    at java.io.PrintWriter.write(PrintWriter.java:456)
    at java.io.PrintWriter.write(PrintWriter.java:473)
    at java.io.PrintWriter.print(PrintWriter.java:603)
    at org.apache.spark.ui.JettyUtils$$anon$2.doGet(JettyUtils.scala:86)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:812)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter.doFilter(AmIpFilter.java:164)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.servlets.gzip.GzipHandler.handle(GzipHandler.java:479)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:311)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:544)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
2017-02-23 21:01:48,024 WARN  org.spark_project.jetty.server.HttpChannel (HttpChannel.java:handle(384)) - /jobs/
```

Comment: Try clearing the cache?

Comment: Hmm. I can try that. However, how do I clean all the available data frame in cache memory from YARN. I know I can clean specific dat frame by df.unpersist(). But if I want to know what all cached objects are there and clean all at once from the YARN cluster any idea?

Comment: @Hng Well I did this : 

SqlContext.clearCache(). So it would clean all the cached variables. However it still didn't seem to work. 

On googling on this error i found it's an issue if two versions of the library are not same (one which spark has etc) So sharding is a method. But then my question is how come it works for some sample data if it is a library version issue?

Answer (score 0):

I have also gone through this error in pyspark, i resolved this problem by adding some jars in spark-submit command.

--jars /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.9.0-1.cdh5.9.0.p0.23/lib/spark/lib/spark-examples-1.6.0-cdh5.9.0-hadoop2.6.0-cdh5.9.0.jar

Comment: i use jupyter.. any idea how to add there?

Comment: import os
os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--jars /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.9.0-1.cdh5.9.0.p0.23/lib/spark/lib/spark-examples-1.6.0-cdh5.9.0-hadoop2.6.0-cdh5.9.0.ja pyspark-shell'

Comment: got this 

  File "<ipython-input-2-61cd6753c275>", line 1
    import os os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--jars /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.9.0-1.cdh5.9.0.p0.23/lib/spark/lib/spark-examples-1.6.0-cdh5.9.0-hadoop2.6.0-cdh5.9.0.ja pyspark-shell' –
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax